# Autowired Environment variable is NULL when @Bean annotated method is executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm attempting to retrieve properties loaded from a .yml file by autowiring an Environment variable, but I'm getting a null pointer exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/example/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I want to programatically create a DataSource bean while keeping the details (username, password, host, etc) in a configuration file. This is  my setup at the moment:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:controllers.xml"})
public class WebApplication{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

```xml
server:
  port: 8080

database:
  host: localhost
  instance: db_instance
  port: 3036
  user: root
  password: passkey
```

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" +
        environment.getProperty("database.host") +
        ":" + environment.getProperty("database.port") +
        "/" + environment.getProperty("database.instance") +
        "?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";

    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        .url(url)
        .username(environment.getProperty("database.user"))
        .password(environment.getProperty("database.password"))
        .build();
  }
}
```

I'm not partial to either the .yml file format or using the Environment variable. If there is a different/better way to go about getting the data from the .yml file (or some other file format), I'm willing to try it.

Comment: dataSource method throws nullpointer somewhere. Some of environment variables might be null. Check your namings, driver, server. Also suggest to use class variable to get environment variables with annotation e.g @Value(${database.user}) String user;  Please try and then I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

1. Since you are using Springboot, you do not have to create a
   Datasource explicitly like this(If you do so, you are missing out on one of the main features of springboot). If you declare the parameters in
   properties/yml with right keys, Springboot with Autoconfigure this
   for you.
   Search for `spring.datasource......` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)
2. If you wish to do this on your own, then You can autowire all the variables in properties/yml file into a Bean using
   `ConfigurationProperties` then use this bean as method parameter in
   your bean creation method.
   check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html) out
3. Use `@Value{}` in your AppConfig class and use it in your Datasource creation method.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I ended up going with option 2. I created a demo project to test it out. I'll post a link to the github repo soon, in case anyone
is interested in seeing how I set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is there in controllers.xml .
But I was able to fetch environment variable and use it.

I placed the properties you mentioned in application.yml in /src/main/resources

I used Spring boot-2.1.9 version to make it work and below is my pom.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>stackoverflow</name>
    <description>stackoverflow</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ojo-snapshots</id>
            <name>OJO Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Comment: `controllers.xml` contains bean definitions (I should rename it to beans.xml). There's a story behind why I've decided to create the dataSource bean programatically, but it's outside the scope of this question, so I wont detail it here, unless someone is interested in knowing how my question came about in the first place.

Comment: Don't load beans via xml. Spring boot will do that automatically for you. You can create the datasource bean programtically as you are doing right now.